# The Hausdorff dimensions of variations of Jarnik sets

Tags: diophantine-approximation, hausdorff-dimension

For $\alpha, \beta>3,$ define
$$\{(x,y)\in[0,1]\times [0,1]: \|qx\|\le q^{1-\alpha}, \|qy\|\le q^{1-\beta} \quad \text{for infinitely many $ q\in \mathbb{N}$}\}.$$
This set can be regarded as a two dimensional variation of the Jarnik set.

Does anybody know some results on the Hausdorff dimension of this set? Many thanks!